# Delphi cxDBTableView versus cxTableView

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am developing a Delphi application which requires dual modes for displaying data. The application will make the decision of connecting to the correct mode during startup time.

First mode is directly bound to a database, so I am going through the usual dataset -> datasource way. Here I am using a cxDBTableView, which is directly connected to the datasource.

However, second mode is through an external library, which is giving me an object list. So, I looked at various options. The best one that I found was using a cxTableView, which is connected to my object list (I have implemented TcxCustomDataSource) using provider mode.

I tried to do this on the cxDBTableView but the provider mode did not work.

I dont want to keep two grids for every form in the application to display between the first mode and second mode.

Any thoughts on how I can consolidate the workflow for both the modes?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Delphi-Developer.

Comment: You are asking for advice, i think there is no technical question. You have many options: grid with 2 views inside (you can switch between DBTableView/TableView any time); grid with DBTableView connected to MemTable (you can fill MemTable as you want); grid with TableView (fill it with data as you want), ... DEX has good support service, ask them directly: www.devexpress.com/Support/Center

Comment: Use a TClientDataSet and cxDBTableView. Then at startup, you can either populate your TClientDataSet from a database or populate it from your object list.